# How to find if scrollview content has reached its end of the content in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, scrollview, swiftui

I m developing an app in SwiftUI. In of my app screens I have a scrollView where I want to find if scrollView has reached its bottom or end of scroll. I m able to find content offset using GeometryReader but could not find a way to figure out the scroll end.

Below is the code I have tried:

```
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {

            GeometryReader { geometry -> Text in
                print("\(self.offsetValue)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.offsetValue = geometry.frame(in: .global).origin.y
                }

            }

        } 
 }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `UIScrollview` in `UIViewRepresentable` that you can achieve the scrollview delegation methods.

also suggesting to read this [article](https://swiftui-lab.com/a-powerful-combo/) that can you understand how it works